# ElectronJS : How to show changes in the code immediately?

Tags: javascript, electron

I am using **ElectronJS** in order to build a Desktop Application.

However, I would like to auto-update the changes in the code and see the result immediately.

For example, if I am creating a WebServer with *express* on *localhost*, alyways when i update the browser, i get the changes.

On the *Go Live* extension on VSCode, this happens automatically after *CRTL + Save*

Does there exist any similar functionality for electron?

My current alternative is to close the whole electron application and start it with *npm start* again...

Thanks.

Comment: This is called hot reload / live reload. You'll need extra dependency. Google it.

Comment: @ShioT You are right. I did not know the term i should search for. However, i found it now.

Answer (score 1):

use **electron-hot-reload** package get hotreload

```
import { mainReloader, rendererReloader } from 'electron-hot-reload';
import { app } from 'electron';
import path from 'path';

const mainFile = path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'dist', 'main.js');
const rendererFile = path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'dist', 'renderer.js');

mainReloader(mainFile, undefined, (error, path) => {
  console.log("It is a main's process hook!");
});

rendererReloader(rendererFile, undefined, (error, path) => {
  console.log("It is a renderer's process hook!");
});
```

**Example project with configuration**

https://github.com/valentineus/electron-hot-reload/tree/6feca4b65b78c674aea096906ecd7b46abebc36a/example/application/src

Answer (score 0):

Found it on my own.
As @ShioT mentioned, this is called *hot reload / live reload*.

**electron-reload**  | **npm package**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-reload

*Frontend*

```
require('electron-reload')(__dirname);
```

*Backend (hard reset)* 
const path = require('path')

```
require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
   // note that this path can vary
  electron: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '.bin', 'electron')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I've found is using [electron-reloader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-reloader), after installation, just paste the following code at the top of the app entry file, and you're all set:

```js
const { app } = require('electron')

app.isPackaged || require('electron-reloader')(module)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution enables hot reloading for
electron + webpack + react
https://github.com/electron/forge/issues/2560